# How to search text in Time Series Collections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried searching text using the condition `{ $text: { $search: searchContent } }`. This requires a text index. However, [text index is not supported by time series](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-55241) . What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `{"field": {"$regex": "value-to-search"}}` as your query, this is the closest to a text search without using one, as you mentioned it is not supported and according to the link you provided it probably will not be.

Answer (score 0):

If you know field what you find, you could use `$regex` same @omercotkd suggest. Here, I use `$where` for the case that you want to search on all field.

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr: {
        $function: {
            body: function(all_field) {
                for (var field in all_field) {
                    if (all_field[field] == searchContent) return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
            args: [ "$$ROOT" ],
            lang: "js"
        }
    }
})
```